# Unable to find a match: python3-routes on Rocky Linux

Tags: python-3.x, linux, yum

```
[root@localhost abc]# sudo yum -y install python3-routes 

Last metadata expiration check: 0:08:56 ago on Thu 06 Oct 2022 04:19:36 PM IST. No match for argument: python3-routes Error: Unable to find a match: python3-routes

[root@localhost abc]#
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable EPEL repo, the package is located [there](https://rhel.pkgs.org/8/epel-x86_64/python3-routes-2.4.1-12.el8.noarch.rpm.html).